# Can't start upstart

Tags: upstart

I want to run upstart job. I've created upstart file and put it to `/etc/init` folder

```
#/etc/init/myjob.conf

description "test job"

start on runlevel [2345]

exec /home/megas/test.sh
```

and then created script in home directory

```
#/home/megas/test.sh

#!/bin/sh
echo "test job, reporting..."
```

Then I'm trying to run

```
sudo start myjob
```

but got message

```
start: Job failed to start
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to create upstart job?

Comment: There should be a log file in /var/log/upstart/myjob.log. Check it's contents and post said contents if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing on `lubuntu 12.04` and the problem is due to wrong permission of `test.sh`, so try:

```
 $ chmod +x /home/megas/test.sh
```

When you start the job:

```
 $ sudo start myjob
 myjob stop/waiting
```

This is normal behavior for task job and `echo` output is stored in:

```
/var/log/upstart/myjob.log
```

According to [upstart manual](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/):

> When a Task Job starts, its goal will be start and once the task in
>   question has completed, Upstart will change its goal to stop.